# How do I associate a nib (.xib) file with a UIView?

Tags: iphone

I have a subclass "s" of UIView.  I want to put some buttons and labels on s.  How do I associate my UIView subclass with a nib file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. In Interface Builder, create a new
   xib with the View template.

   - Click on the view in the list of
     objects in the xib (you should also
     see "File's Owner and "First
     Responder").
   - Push Cmd-4 to open the Identity pane
     of the inspector.
   - Type your class's name into the
     "Class Name" field and push return.

You should be able the drag buttons in. To get at the nib from code, use `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`. Your view should be the first object in the returned array.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing - Do you know what classname I should be using for (a) parent UIControllerView and (b) the custom UIView itself here? I've noted in my code I have my custom UIView class name in both but that giving me a recursive call to my custom UIView init method. That is I have (a) in the parent UIControllerView which uses my custom view, in IB for it's XIB I use a UIView which I've set the classname to "clockview", but then (b) in my actual clockview custom UIView (not UIControllerView) XIB file I've done the same thing and set the class name to be "clockview".

Comment: @Colin Do we really need to set the `File's Owner` to the custom UIView class? I don't see any difference setting it to either `UIView`  or `myCustomView`. What is the purpose of `File's Owner` in this case?

Comment: I want to be able to use a UIView with a nib in multiple places. Is there a way of doing it without having to wire up the IBOutlets every time?

Comment: In XCode 4.5, I've needed to clean and shut down XCode for the UIView class to show up in the "Custom Class" list where the properties you need to link to exist.

Comment: can anybody post how to properly load and display that UIView? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I didn't want my view controller to have any knowledge of the IBOutlets from my view's .xib. I wanted my view subclass to own the IBOutlets. Unfortunately UIView doesn't have an `initWithNibName:` method, so I just created my own category.

Here's what I did:

- In IB, click on your main UIView, and in the Identity Inspector, set the class to your subclass
- In IB, click on File's Owner, and in the Identity Inspector, set the class to your subclass
- Use your new category method `initWithNibName:` to instantiate your view.

And here's the category I created:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
{
    NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
    if (arrayOfViews.count < 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    self = arrayOfViews[0];

    return self;
}
```

Inspired by [this post](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2578-loading-a-nib-file-programmatically-objective-c/).

Note though, that so far the frame will adjust automatically, so unlike the code in the post, I haven't yet had to explicitly set the frame.
Also, unlike the post's code, I needed to set `owner:self` so the IBOutlets would be wired up correctly.